# How to remove multiple words from a string Java

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I'm new to java and currently, I'm learning strings.

How to remove multiple words from a string?

I would be glad for any hint.

```
class WordDeleterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordDeleter wordDeleter = new WordDeleter();

        // Hello
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("Hello Java", new String[] { "Java" }));

        // The Athens in
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("The Athens is in Greece", new String[] { "is", "Greece" }));
    }
}

class WordDeleter {
    public String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {
        String[] array = phrase.split(" ");
        String word = "";
        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            word += words[i];
        }
        for (String newWords : array) {
            if (!newWords.equals(word)) {
                result += newWords + " ";
            }
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
The Athens is in Greece
```

I've already tried to use replacе here, but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps the bug is in the loop where you are building the variable word?  I'm not sure what your intent is to have that for loop just build word variable.  Which will likely result in the word "isGreece" which will not equal any of the  words in the second loop.  Rework that bit and you are close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmers often do this:

```
String sentence = "Hello Java World!";
sentence.replace("Java", "");
System.out.println(sentence);
```

=> Hello Java World

Strings are immutable, and the replace function returns a new string object. So instead write

```
String sentence = "Hello Java World!";
sentence = sentence.replace("Java", "");
System.out.println(sentence);
```

=> Hello  World!

(the whitespace still exists)

With that, your replace function could look like

```
public String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {
    String result = phrase;
    for (String word: words) {
        result = result.replace(word, "").replace("  ", " ");
    }
    return result.trim();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hiran, I've tried to use replace, but didn't figure out that I should use it two times

Comment: The second call is just to remove a double whitespace since the first one just removes the word.

Comment: Ah, damn, doesn't work
With the string "This is Sparta" with the word to remove "is", it outputs "Th Sparta"

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. So the replace must not happen on the full phrase, just on words. In that case Michail's solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using streams:

```java
String phrase = ...;
List<String> wordsToRemove = ...;
        
String result = Arrays.stream(phrase.split("\s+"))
     .filter(w -> !wordsToRemove.contains(w))
     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Hello @OrestDymarchuk, from Athens, Greece! i just wanted to highlight the stream approach. By the way, the `wordsToRemove` can also be represented as a `Set<String>` which (if are plenty of them) will be far more effective (the `Set.contains` method will run in logarithmic time)